# Display worldclock using a parameters from sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript

I need to display a worldclock (Time from some contries) using Javascript and retrieving a list from SharePoint. 
My code is not working could someone help me please.
Here's my code. 
Thanks

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divListItems"></div>

<script language="JavaScript">

$(function () {
            ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(retrieveListItems, "sp.js");
        });

function retrieveListItems() {

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Horloge');
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
    clientContext.load(collListItem);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),
    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
    );
}       
<!--
function worldClock(zone, region){
var dst = 0
var time = new Date()
var gmtMS = time.getTime() + (time.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000)
var gmtTime = new Date(gmtMS)
var day = gmtTime.getDate()
var month = gmtTime.getMonth()
var year = gmtTime.getYear()
if(year < 1000){
year += 1900
}
var monthArray = new Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", 
                "September", "October", "November", "December")
var monthDays = new Array("31", "28", "31", "30", "31", "30", "31", "31", "30", "31", "30", "31")
if (year%4 == 0){
monthDays = new Array("31", "29", "31", "30", "31", "30", "31", "31", "30", "31", "30", "31")
}
if(year%100 == 0 && year%400 != 0){
monthDays = new Array("31", "28", "31", "30", "31", "30", "31", "31", "30", "31", "30", "31")
}

var hr = gmtTime.getHours() + zone
var min = gmtTime.getMinutes()
var sec = gmtTime.getSeconds()

if (hr >= 24){
hr = hr-24
day -= -1
}
if (hr < 0){
hr -= -24
day -= 1
}
if (hr < 10){
hr = " " + hr
}
if (min < 10){
min = "0" + min
}
if (sec < 10){
sec = "0" + sec
}
if (day <= 0){
if (month == 0){
    month = 11
    year -= 1
    }
    else{
    month = month -1
    }
day = monthDays[month]
}
if(day > monthDays[month]){
    day = 1
    if(month == 11){
    month = 0
    year -= -1
    }
    else{
    month -= -1
    }
}



if (dst == 1){
    hr -= -1
    if (hr >= 24){
    hr = hr-24
    day -= -1
    }
    if (hr < 10){
    hr = " " + hr
    }
    if(day > monthDays[month]){
    day = 1
    if(month == 11){
    month = 0
    year -= -1
    }
    else{
    month -= -1
    }
    }
return monthArray[month] + " " + day + ", " + year + "<br>" + hr + ":" + min + ":" + sec + " DST"
}
else{
return monthArray[month] + " " + day + ", " + year + "<br>" + hr + ":" + min + ":" + sec
}
}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {

    var t = new Array();
    var oListItem;
    var listItemInfo="";
    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        listItemInfo +=
        ' <strong>City:</strong> ' + oListItem.get_item('City') +
        ' <strong>Zone:</strong> ' + oListItem.get_item('Zone') +
        ' <strong>TimeZone:</strong> ' + oListItem.get_item('TimeZone') +
        '<br />';
        t.push([oListItem.get_item,oListItem.get_item('Zone'),oListItem.get_item('TimeZone')]);
    }
    $("#divListItems").html(listItemInfo);
    for (i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
        //marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            //position: new google.maps.LatLng(t[i][1], t[i][2]),
           // map: map
          worldclockZone( document.getElementById(" oListItem.get_item('City')").innerHTML=worldClock(t[i][1],t[i][2]))
        });

window.onload=worldClockZone;

//-->
</script
```

>

Comment: so, why isn't it working? You have to be very specific with what's happening. Saying it doesn't work doesn't really tell us a story we can finish.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is wrong with the code. I found another site that has javascript to add a clock to a page. I gave it a try and it worked for me.
https://www.ricocheting.com/code/javascript/html-generator/date-time-clock